# How to set up sub-subdomain on Github Pages

Tags: github, subdomain

I currently have my blog hosted on Github Pages and am using custom domains of the type `mydomain.toplevel` and `www.mydomain.toplevel`.

How can I set up a sub-subdomain of the type `two.words.mydomain.toplevel` and `www.two.words.mydomain.toplevel` and point them to a specific directory?

I've found enough information on how to set up a single subdomain, but none of what I found seems to carry over to sub-subdomains in a straightforward way.

I appreciate any pointers. Please note I still want to be able to reach my blog at its current URL. I'm not very experienced with this stuff and I set up my current URL using the Github.com graphical interface, which doesn't include any options for subdomains (let alone sub-subdomains).

Comment: What company did you buy `toplevel.com` from? You may have to go to their website to try to configure these things. In case it helps: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-sub-subdomain/

Comment: I've seen that very website, but it focuses on sub-domains. Not sub-subdomains. My URL is with GoDaddy.com and I've set it up there to point to the Github Pages webspace.

Comment: Did you read the bottom of it? It talks about sub-subdomains... nonetheless, here's another link that may be of help. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65581/how-can-i-add-sub1-sub2-domain-com-to-my-godaddy-hosting-account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a "**A** or **CNAME** " record in your domain control panel (GODADDY/BigRock etc..) 
like https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-that-points-to-an-ip-address-4080
you need to point to ip addresses **192.30.252.153 or 192.30.252.154**

then goto your pages repository settings and add your subdomain in the custom domain textbox. 
save it.

now it works like magic.

Comment: Must the page be in a separate repo if i want to retain the URL without subdomain pointing to my main blog page?

Comment: On GoDaddy's DNS management interface, I'm getting the error message "The specified record already exists" because my user page is already set up with my custom domain (and it's supposed to stay that way). I don't see a way to add the sub-domain without removing the A record or CNAME record for my main page, which I don't want.

Comment: Yes you need to have multiple repos to use multiple domains/subdomains. For now github is allowing one custom domain or subdomain.  To add subdomain Add **A** record for sub domain.